# Linq Subquery same Table

Tags: c#, linq

I've a table with Id and CategoryId.

I need to get all records from that table with same CategoryId as the given Id.

This is what I came up to:

```
var query = from x in erm.Projects
            where x.CategoryId == erm.Projects.Where(y => y.Id == lookId).FirstOrDefault().CategoryId
            select x;
```

What's the best way to do this query?

Thank you

Comment: And what problems do you have using that solution?

Comment: Also, what query provider are you using?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a join to do this sort of thing. Also has the advantage of avoiding a `NullReferenceException` if `FirstOrDefault()` returns null and you call `.CategoryId` on it blindly.

```
var query = erm.Table.Join(erm.Projects.Where(y => y.Id == lookId), x => x.CategoryId, y => y.CategoryId, (x,y) => x);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int catId = erm.Projects.Where(y => y.Id == lookId).FirstOrDefault().CategoryId;

var results = erm.Table
             .Where(x=> x.CategoryId == catId)
             .ToList();
```

OR;

```
var query = from t in erm.Table join p in erm.Projects
                 on t.CategoryId equals p.CategoryId
            where p.CategoryId = lookId
            select t;
```

Comment: The lookId is a Table.Id and not a Table.CategoryId

Comment: Is this what you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way.

```
var categoryId= erm.Projects.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Id == lookId).CategoryId;

var results = erm.Table
             .Where(x=> x.CategoryId == categoryId)
             .ToList();
```